# iOS native way to share files to any possible apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload, native, file-sharing

I'm currently implementing an iOS app using objective-C, which has a function that users may share a file with other friend or other app (like upload the file to Dropbox, Google Drive, attach the file to Mail, share the file to Facebook Messenger, Whatsapp, via Bluetooth, etc).

Is there a native way to implement this share function that can detect all apps which allows sharing a file, while I don't need to do it one by one?

Comment: you can use ActivityController....

Comment: Also look at `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `UIActivityViewController`. Below is an example from [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/), which is probably the most comprehensive article I've seen on the subject.  And Apple has some good documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/).

```
NSString *string = ...;
NSURL *URL = ...;

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[string, URL]
                                applicationActivities:nil];
[navigationController presentViewController:activityViewController
                                  animated:YES
                                completion:^{
     // ...
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

This provide full answer for iPhone and iPad devices

```
ViewController *contentViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

// Present the view controller using the popover style.
contentViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
[self presentViewController:contentViewController 
                   animated:YES 
                 completion:nil];

// Get the popover presentation controller and configure it.
UIPopoverPresentationController *presentationController =[contentViewController popoverPresentationController];
presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
presentationController.sourceView = self.view;
presentationController.sourceRect = self.view.frame;
```

[UIPopoverPresentationController should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs on iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920340/uipopoverpresentationcontroller-should-have-a-non-nil-sourceview-or-barbuttonite)