# UIPopoverPresentationController should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs on iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, exception, ios9, subclassing, uipresentationcontroller

I'm trying to show a popup using a custom UIPopoverPresentationController class. But it crashes with the error`(<UIPopoverPresentationController: 0x7a772950>) should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.` Below is my button click code where the crash occurs.

```
- (IBAction)showPopup:(UIButton *)sender {
ViewController *contentViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    contentViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200);
    contentViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    myPopoverController *popOver = [[myPopoverController alloc]initWithPresentedViewController:contentViewController presentingViewController:self andTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

    popOver.delegate = self;
    popOver.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
    popOver.sourceRect = sender.frame;
    popOver.sourceView = self.view;
    [self presentViewController:contentViewController animated: YES completion: nil];
}
```

Below is a sample of how my custom UIPopoverPresentationController looks like

```
myPopoverController.h file

@interface myPopoverController : UIPopoverPresentationController

@property (readonly) UIColor *tintColor;


-(instancetype)initWithPresentedViewController:(UIViewController *)presentedViewController presentingViewController:(UIViewController *)presentingViewController andTintColor:(UIColor *)aTintColor;

@end


myPopoverController.m file

//Some code for UIPopoverBackgroundView

-(instancetype)initWithPresentedViewController:(UIViewController *)presentedViewController presentingViewController:(UIViewController *)presentingViewController
{

    self = [self initWithPresentedViewController:presentedViewController presentingViewController:presentingViewController andTintColor: [UIColor redColor]];

    return self;
}


-(instancetype)initWithPresentedViewController:(UIViewController *)presentedViewController presentingViewController:(UIViewController *)presentingViewController andTintColor:(UIColor *)aTintColor
{

    self = [super initWithPresentedViewController:presentedViewController presentingViewController:presentingViewController];

    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    [super setPopoverBackgroundViewClass: [myPopoverControllerBackgroundView class]];
    tintColor = aTintColor;


    return self;
}
```

I don't have a barbutton but I'm setting the sourceView. Am I doing something wrong here? Appreciate your help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a popover presentation controller like this also and it may work

```
- (IBAction)showPopup:(UIButton *)sender {

ViewController *contentViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    contentViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200);
    contentViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

UIPopoverPresentationController *popoverpresentationController = contentViewController.popoverPresentationController;
    popoverpresentationController.delegate = self;
    popoverpresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
    popoverpresentationController.sourceRect = sender.bounds;
    popoverpresentationController.sourceView = sender;
    [self presentViewController:contentViewController animated: YES completion: nil];
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If sourceView is null, just add a validation

```
UIActivityViewController * avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareItems applicationActivities:nil];
if(avc.popoverPresentationController){
    avc.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
}
[self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[See this post](https://dushyant37.medium.com/how-to-present-uiactivityviewcontroller-on-iphone-and-ipad-ae72013d2a5a)

Comment: This worked for me. I was encountering a crash only on iPad (and not iPhone or iPod Touch). Actually I had to replace `.sourceView` with `.barButtonItem` and set it equal to the bar button item I had added to my `navigationController.navigationItem`.

Comment: You also have to set the `sourceRect` otherwise the popover won't display

Comment: You need to set `popOver.permittedArrowDirections = 0;`, so that there are no arrows. If not set the popup didn't display for me (maybe because my source view is full screen). If I had arrows I needed to specify `.sourceRect` as well. I gave it the view.bounds but maybe because it was full screen view it didn't show the popup. I gave it something "imaginary"  `CGRectMake(view.origin.x, view.origin.y, 0, 0);`

Comment: This answer is incomplete. I tried this code and I did not see any popover.

Answer (score 6):

You are subclassing the `UIPopoverPresentationController` but Apple [recommends](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontroller) to use them as they are. Once you present a `UIViewController`, a `UIPopoverPresentationController` will be automatically created and you are supposed to modify it for your needs.

You create an `myPopoverController` instance but Apple creates another when you `present` your `contentViewController` right after:

```
[self presentViewController:contentViewController animated: YES completion: nil];
```

This new `UIPopoverPresentationController` lacks the `sourceView` and throws an exception.

Try the code below instead:

```
ViewController *contentViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

// Present the view controller using the popover style.
contentViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
[self presentViewController:contentViewController 
                   animated:YES 
                 completion:nil];

// Get the popover presentation controller and configure it.
UIPopoverPresentationController *presentationController =[contentViewController popoverPresentationController];
presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
presentationController.sourceView = self.view;
presentationController.sourceRect = sender.frame;
```

Comment: You inverted sourceView and sourceRect assignments in the last two lines of your sample.

Answer (score 2):

May be below code could help:

In `iPad` the view controller will be displayed as a popover using the new `UIPopoverPresentationController`, it requires to specify an anchor point for the presentation of the popover using one of the three following properties:

1. `barButtonItem`
2. `sourceView`
3. `sourceRect`

Do as follows:

```
//for iPhone
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

}
//for iPad
else {
    // Change Rect as required
    ViewController *contentViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    contentViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200);
    contentViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    [self presentViewController:contentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: UIPopoverController is deprecated from iOS 9 onwards

Answer (score 2):

The Best way I think is override present method

```
extension XXXBaseViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        if let popController = viewControllerToPresent.popoverPresentationController,
            popController.sourceView == nil{
            return
        }
        super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Comment: I once encountered a situation。If there is not enough memory, it will be automatically reclaimed

Answer (score 0):

my two cents for activity (and in swift 5..)

..

```
 let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
                activityItems: shareTextAndImg, applicationActivities: [])
 if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
   activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = btn
  }

present(activityViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: What's in the `btn` variable?

Comment: btw is the button in UI where present it.